# Databinding in xaml SelectedItem

Tags: c#, xaml

Please have a look at this:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
          DataContext="{StaticResource vm}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="194*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="489*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListView HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Places}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedPlace, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="0,96,0,0">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">

         <TextBlock
         VerticalAlignment="Top"
         Text="{Binding SelectedPlace.Title}" Margin="0,64,0,0"/>
        </StackPanel>


    </Grid>
```

I am passing in list of Places, its working fine and the list gets displayed in the view. The problem is the `selectedItem`. The intellisense finds the property here

```
 Text="{Binding SelectedPlace.Title}"
```

But it does not show up in the view. 
When I put a breakpoint in my viewmodel, I can see that that value changes:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Place> Places { get; set; }

        public Place _selectedPlace { get; set; }

        public Place SelectedPlace
        {
            get { return _selectedPlace; }
            set { _selectedPlace = value; }
        }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            Places = new ObservableCollection<Place>()
            {
                new Place() {Title = "London", Description = "London is a nice..."},
                new Place() {Title = "Dublin", Description = "Dublin is a ...."}
            };
        }
    }
```

Does anyone know what i am missing? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to invoke RaisePropertyChanged.

```
        public Place SelectedPlace
        {
            get { return _selectedPlace; }
            set
            {    _selectedPlace = value; 
                 RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedPlace")}
            }
        }
```

And you should probably also initialize this property:

```
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Places = new ObservableCollection<Place>()
        {
            new Place() {Title = "London", Description = "London is a nice..."},
            new Place() {Title = "Dublin", Description = "Dublin is a ...."}
        };
        SelectedPlace = Places[0];
    }
```

And do yourself a favor by making the backing field of the SelectedPlace property a private field. You probably want to change it as this:

```
public Place _selectedPlace { get; set; }
```

to

```
private Place _selectedPlace;
```